# Passing a Type variable to a generic method

Tags: c#, generics

I am aware this question may have been asked a thousand times but haven't managed to find the solution I seek on similar threads.

I have the following method which converts an object type to a generic type provided by the caller of the method.

```
public static T ConvertValue<T>(object value)
{
    //conversion code
}
```

I am trying to use this method to convert the value type of an object's properties using Reflection.

Supposing we have the following object:

```
SomeClass someObject;
PropertyInfo myProperty = someObject.GetType().GetProperty("somePropertyName")
```

The following code works just fine:

```
string propertyValue = ConvertValue<string>(myProperty.GetValue(someObject));
```

However this forces me to write down the desired conversion type, while what I'd like to do is:

```
Type myPropertyType = prop.PropertyType;
var propertyValue = ConvertValue<myPropertyType>(myProperty.GetValue(someObject));
```

I understand usage is not intended by the compiler for various reasons, but I just can't come up with a simple solution for this..

Most solutions I found suggested passing the Type as a parameter and returning an object type.

```
public static object ConvertValue(object value, Type type)
{
    //conversion code
}
```

But this seems to defeat the whole purpose as I must then make a cast of the output...

Comment: You're still specifying the type by declaring `property_value` as `string`. It's not clear how you expect this to work - what is the relationship between `myPropertyType` and `string` in this case?

Comment: You can´t expect your compiler to infer a type you provide at runtime. Thus you *allways* have to do the cast to that actual type as otherwise your method just returns an `object`.

Comment: @Lee oops sorry I meant to assign the **var** type instead of string